# performing more that two actions in ternary conditional operator

Tags: python

I want to perform two actions in one single line of code in python ternary conditional operator.

Here is traditional if else statement in Python:

```
if Condition:
   a
   b
else:
   c
```

Can i write this code to perform a and b in one single line of code in ternary conditional operator like below, i tried this one but i'm getting SyntaxError

```
a,b if condition else c
```

P.S. I am beginner

Comment: Try it buddy, you might be surprised

Comment: please dont jump into the "must do everything in one line" bandwagon. There is nothing pretty about doing stuff in one line if it hinders readability. As for this particular case, ternary operators were intended to return a single response for true and false cases

Comment: this `a,b if condition else c` thing works. Try `3,4 if 1 else 2`... but don't use ternary for side effects.

Comment: An conditional expression can only contain *expressions*; an `if` statement can contain statements, some which may be expression statements (i.e., expressions used as statement). They are not meant to be interchangeable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `3, 4 if 0 else 2` will return `(3, 2)` which is not what would be expected by the OP.

Comment: i tried ```deck(), play = True if input("Do you want to play again?").startswith('y') else play = False```  but i am getting SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone oh right!! My answer advised to put parentheses. I was right at first :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah with parentheses it works :-)

Comment: when you don't know, always put parentheses

Comment: @RJT now it looks like you are trying to call a method and assign a variable as part of this. Now that I don't think you can do. Unless you pass in the variable to a method and assign it there. This is exactly why you should avoid these "clever" one liners though...

Comment: i already tried by using parentheses  but still getting invalid syntax

Comment: @RJT that's because you are trying to do variable assignment now and not just run a method. Your question was not clear on that. See my comment above on ways around it or better off, just do a normal if, else statement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below works but it's pretty bad practice and horrible for readability.

I would just stick to the standard traditional `if, else` statement you mention in your question:

```
def do_a():
    print 'a'

def do_b():
    print 'b'

def do_c():
    print 'c'
```

Running a test in a console:

```
>>> (do_a(), do_b()) if True else do_c()
a
b

>>> (do_a(), do_b()) if False else do_c()
c
```